# StaxEventItemWriter error - org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: File already exists:

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I was trying to create a springboot batch job, which has to read data's from a queue, and write into xml format. I am using `StaxEventItemWriter` for writing , and while running the application I am getting following error. I strongly believe the error is in the itemwriter section, because with the same reader, I am able to write to a flat file using Filefileitemwriter. I am not able to find out what I did wrong. I am really appriciate your help.

> [org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute] Encountered
>   an error executing step step1 in job importUserJob
>   org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: File already
>   exists: [C:\folder\Sync_0.xml]    at
>   org.springframework.batch.item.util.FileUtils.setUpOutputFile(FileUtils.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter.open(StaxEventItemWriter.java:428)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter.open(StaxEventItemWriter.java:400)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:310)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:216)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:233)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:119)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:806)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:790)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:777)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)

Code for itemwriter is provided below.

```
@Bean
public ItemWriter<WorkerXML> staxEventItemWriter() throws XmlMappingException, Exception{
  StaxEventItemWriter<WorkerXML> staxEventItemWriter = new StaxEventItemWriter<WorkerXML>();

  try{

    XStreamMarshaller marshaller = new XStreamMarshaller(); 

    staxEventItemWriter.setName("StaxEventItemWriter");
          staxEventItemWriter.setResource("C://folder//Sync_0.xml"));

    staxEventItemWriter.setRootTagName("WorkerXML");
    staxEventItemWriter.setOverwriteOutput(false);
    staxEventItemWriter.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    staxEventItemWriter.setEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());

    staxEventItemWriter.setVersion("XML");//    

    staxEventItemWriter.setSaveState(true);        //                             staxEventItemWriter.open(new ExecutionContext());

    ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
    staxEventItemWriter.open(executionContext);

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("staxEventItemWriter " + e);
    }
    return staxEventItemWriter;
  }

  @Bean 
  public Marshaller marshaller() 
  { 
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(QVCWorkerXML.class);
    return marshaller;
  }
```

Comment: you set overwriteoutput to false; therefore, if the file is already there, it will not overwrite it but throw an exception instead.

Comment: I was tested in both ways, with overwriteoutput as true and false. In both cases, I am getting the error.  Did you see any mistake in the marshalling section? My settings for staxEventItemWriter and Jaxb2Marshaller is correct?